# Вывод блоков из файла

Tags: bash, awk

Выбрать блок начинающийся с "189 common" заканчивающийся на "48"
Пример файла:

```
2992 common TG:XGE0/0/31(U) XGE0/0/32(U) XGE0/0/33(U) XGE0/0/34(U)   
  XGE0/0/35(U) XGE0/0/36(U) XGE0/0/37(U) XGE0/0/38(U)  
  XGE0/0/39(U) XGE0/0/47(U) XGE0/0/48(D)  
2993 common TG:XGE0/0/31(U) XGE0/0/32(U) XGE0/0/33(U) XGE0/0/34(U)  
  XGE0/0/35(U) XGE0/0/36(U) XGE0/0/37(U) XGE0/0/38(U)  
  XGE0/0/39(U) XGE0/0/47(U) XGE0/0/48(D)    
2994 common TG:XGE0/0/31(U) XGE0/0/32(U) XGE0/0/33(U) XGE0/0/34(U)  
  XGE0/0/35(U) XGE0/0/36(U) XGE0/0/37(U) XGE0/0/38(U)  
  XGE0/0/39(U) XGE0/0/47(U) XGE0/0/48(D)    
2995 common TG:XGE0/0/31(U) XGE0/0/32(U) XGE0/0/33(U) XGE0/0/34(U)  
  XGE0/0/35(U) XGE0/0/36(U) XGE0/0/37(U) XGE0/0/38(U)  
  XGE0/0/39(U) XGE0/0/47(U) XGE0/0/48(D)    
2996 common TG:XGE0/0/31(U) XGE0/0/32(U) XGE0/0/33(U) XGE0/0/34(U)  
  XGE0/0/35(U) XGE0/0/36(U) XGE0/0/37(U) XGE0/0/38(U)  
  XGE0/0/39(U) XGE0/0/47(U) XGE0/0/48(D)
```

вот так работает:

```
cat vlan_port_hu.db | awk ' /^189 common/,/48/ {print} '
```

но мне надо в место "189" подставлять значение из переменной:
Пробую вот так:

```
#/bin/bash
while read vlanid vlanname
do
cat vlan_port_hu.db | awk ' /^$vlanid common/,/48/ {print} '
done < ~/vlan_hu.db
```

Не работает.
Как сделать? Очень желательно на bash, но можно и на других языках.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы использовать переменные окружения [в качестве плейсхолдеров в строках](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html), необходимо строку обрамлять двойными кавычками `"`, т.е.

```
VAL=2993; cat vlan_port_hu.db | awk " /^${VAL} common/,/2995/ {print} "
```

Подобное соглашение используется и в некоторых языках программирования.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете передать переменную как это:

```
awk -v myvar="$bash_var" '{ myvar ... }' file
```

В вашем случае:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r vlanid vlanname
do
    awk -v var=$vlanid '$0 ~ "^" var " common", /48/' vlan_port_hu.db
done < ~/vlan_hu.db
```

#### Test

```
$ seq 20 > a
$ awk -v var=5 '$0 ~ "^" var,/12/' a
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
$ awk -v var=7 '$0 ~ "^" var,/12/' a
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Comment: awk: fatal: cannot open file `$0 ~ "^" var " common", /48/' for reading (Нет такого файла или каталога)

Comment: @Izya12 какая команда вам работать именно?